# how to redirect output of program to a file

Tags: linux, shell, stdout

I am running this program called Genetorrent in Linux. It keeps printing out downloading status update. I wanted to redirect the output to a file instead of displaying on screen. Tried the following neither seem to work.

```
gtdownload [option & parameter] > gt.log
gtdownload [options & parameters] 2>&1 | tee gt.log
```

First one, output to screen, nothing in gt.log. Second one, output to both screen and file at the same time.

Can't even put the task to background, it will still printing out to screen after I did Ctrl+z and "bg". If I close the terminal window the task would quit.

For this type of program, how do I put them to back and output to a file?

Comment: Very convenient: `nohup gtdownload ... &` does all the redirecting for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
gtdownload [option & parameter] > gt.log 2>gt.error
```

The messages that are output to the console in the first case might be caused by messages appearing on `stderr`

Answer (score 1):

Or simply put all output to a single file:

```
gtdownload [option & parameter] > gt.log 2>&1
gtdownload [option & parameter] &> gt.log  ## Bash only
```

Or append:

```
gtdownload [option & parameter] >> gt.log 2>&1
```